# Need Help To Fix Query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Currently I face problem when exporting a table to the new one I have created, which has different structure.

I have table A like this :

```
id  curr1  price1  curr2  price2  curr3  price3
a   USD    20      USD    10      USD    8
b   USD    30      USD    13      USD    11
c   USD    10      USD    5       USD    4
```

And i need to get result like this (sorry i forgot to include name column):

```
a    curr1 USD   20      
a    curr2 USD   10 
a    curr3 USD   8  
b    curr1 USD   30       
b    curr2 USD   13 
b    curr3 USD   11 
c    curr1 USD   10      
c    curr2 USD   5  
c    curr3 USD   4
```

Any idea how to achieve the result using query? Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please have a look at `UNPIVOT` / possible duplicate of [Unpivot Data Scenario to Solve?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118049/unpivot-data-scenario-to-solve)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT  id, currname, curr, price 
FROM [Table]
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT 'curr1' currname, curr1, price1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'curr2' currname, curr2, price2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'curr3' currname, curr3, price3
) c (currname, curr, price)
```

OR you can `UNPIVOT` your data:

```
SELECT id, currname, curr, price
FROM 
( 
    SELECT id, curr1, price1, curr2, price2, curr3, price3
    FROM [Table] 
) t
UNPIVOT 
( 
    curr FOR currname IN (curr1, curr2, curr3) 
) c
UNPIVOT 
( 
    price FOR pricename IN (price1, price2, price3) 
) p
WHERE RIGHT(currname,1) =  RIGHT(pricename,1)
```

*Edited to include your second column

Comment: I think the version with CROSS APPLY is the most practical

Comment: I agree, that's easiest to write, easiest to understand.

Comment: I tried cross apply , but it says error near APPLY.. (nb: im using sql server 2000).. is it query not complete?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no CROSS APPLY and no PIVOT in SQL Server 2000. Please tag your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select * from 
(
    select id, 'curr1' as field, curr1 as curr, price1 as price
    from tableA

    union all

    select id, 'curr2', curr2, price2
    from tableA

    union all

    select id, 'curr3', curr3, price3
    from tableA
) as T
order by T.id asc, T.field asc
```

Here I'm supposing from your output that you need some order in your data. If you don't really need it - then just throw it away and use only internal selects